# How to auto re-route other country traffic except USA to a default web page?

Tags: php, redirect

I want to limit full functionality access to my website to users accessing it from USA only. Any users trying to access the website from any other country I want to identify that traffic based on IP or however possible that the user is not based in USA and display a default webpage like "We will be launching in your country soon" .. etc. message.

I have seen this functionality implemented by spotify.com and netflix.com and got a similar coming soon page when I tried to access the sites from India. 
How do I implement this using PHP?

Thanks for any direction or insight.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to employ a geolocation service. Some are free, some are not:

[Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/html/technology/products/edgescape.html), [Quova](http://www.quova.com/), Digital Envoy ([Digital Element service](http://www.digitalelement.com/)), Google (JavaScript), [Maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location), [hostip.info](http://hostip.info), [Geobytes](http://www.geobytes.com/), [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/), [IP-GEO](https://ip-geo.appspot.com/).

Some services you need to connect each time to make a query (you can cache the results). Other services allow you to download a database of IP-to-country mappings.